# Get error from Simple Html Dom when i want to read URLs from .txt file

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When I read the URL from URL file and pass it into `file_get_html()` method I get this error...

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.xxxxxxx.ir/brand/perfume/Aigner ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in F:\wamp\www\atr\index.php on line 89
```

And this is my code:

```
$fup=fopen("fileurl.txt","r");//read from the file of urls

$string=fgets($fup);get line from file of urls

$html=file_get_contents("$string");
```

And this the code of make URL and put in `fileurl.txt`:

```
function mkurl($burl,$furl){
    $fup=fopen("fileurl.txt","w");
    $fbp=fopen("$furl","r");
    while(!feof($fbp)){
       $mku=$burl.fgets($fbp);
       fwrite($fup,"$mku");
   }
   fclose($fup);
   fclose($fbp);
}
```

I think I have problem with reading from file and putting 
it in `file_get_html()`. And about `fgets()` and `fwrite()` because those put additional character in URL and cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the line you get from the file, because you might get any new line characters along the way.

```
$string=trim(fgets($fup)); //get line from file of urls
```

To see the extra characters you need to go over the string and analyze using the `ord` function.
Example

```
foreach ($string as $char) print ord($char) . ", ";
```

and check the ASCII codes for the first and last characters.

Comment: ...thanks my friend...but now i want to know what character it get?

Comment: you are welcome, but I don't understand your question

Comment: .i want to know when i put and get strings in file.txt what character added to it?

Comment: but now get another error! maximum execution in php! how to solve it?

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to check the ASCII codes for the extra characters. I see you are now asking another question, please consider accepting my answer if it has been usefull